# How to execute stored procedure from Nodejs

Tags: sql-server, node.js, stored-procedures

I have this router in nodejs and I want to execute a stored procedure:

```
router.post('/upadateCreateSiteMonth', isAuthed, function(req, res) {
        //console.log('REQ USER', req.user);
        var q = 'USE [EYE]' +
                'GO' +
                'DECLARE    @return_value int' +
                'EXEC   @return_value = [dbo].[uspCreateSiteMonthConsumption]' +
                'SELECT \'Return Value\' = @return_value' +
                'GO'
        exp.emitter.emit('mssql',{ q: q}, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).json({ error : err });  
            } else {
                res.status(200).json(data);  
            }
       });
    });
```

When I write this in SQL Server database it is ok

```
DECLARE @return_value INT
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[uspCreateSiteMonthConsumption]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

How can I write the variable `q` to respond with 200 this router?

A simple query like `Select * from table` works ok, but when I try to use this query to run the stored procedure, I get a response of 500.

Comment: Why don't you try to use Scalar Function instead of Stored Procedure

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a stored procedure with NodeJS and MSSQL package error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909920/running-a-stored-procedure-with-nodejs-and-mssql-package-error)

Comment: You *shouldn't* try to run anything like that. Instead of using parameterized queries you are using plain old string concatenation that exposes you to SQL Injection attacks. Whatever library you use you shouldn't have to specify more than the name of the stored procedure in the query and the parameter names and values *separately*.

Comment: BTW unless you care about the return value, you could just write `exec dbo.uspCreateSiteMonthConsumption` or even `uspCreateSiteMonthConsumption`

Comment: When i execute `exec dbo.uspCreateSiteMonthConsumption`  i take error `{ RequestError: Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET o
peration.`

Comment: When I execute `DECLARE @return_value int EXECUTE @return_value = [dbo].[uspCreateSiteMonthConsumption];` i take error `{ RequestError: Incorrect syntax near '@return_value'.
    at StreamEvents.<anonymous> (c:\eye.v3\node_modules\mssql\lib\msnodesqlv8.js
:624:21)`

Comment: I executed `SET ansi_warnings off EXEC [dbo].[uspCreateSiteMonthConsumption]` now i don't have the same error