# node-mssql won't execute stored procedure giving unhandlePromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-mssql

The following is the output from my server.js file.
I am printing out the query string parameters that I'm passing into the stored procedure.

```
ID : 10################_
Email : test@mail.com
Name : testname
FamilyName : testtesttest
```

Below this is the error I'm getting:

> (node:8084) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of
>   undefined
>
> (node:8084) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections
>   are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled
>   will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Below is my call to the stored procedure.  I keep getting the above error and the stored procedure is not being executed.  I've looked at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909920/running-a-stored-procedure-with-nodejs-and-mssql-package-error) that appeared to have the same problem, but I'm still getting the same error.

This is my 1st attempt to call a stored procedure using this node module.  So any assistance is appreciated.

```
app.get('/addRegistration', function(req,res){
    try 
    {
        const pool5 = new sql2.ConnectionPool(config, err => 
            {
                // Stored Procedure
                pool5.request()
                .input('FBID', sql2.varchar, 250, req.query.id)
                .input('FBEmail', sql2.varchar, 250, req.query.email)
                .input('FBName', sql2.varchar, 250, req.query.memberName)
                .input('FamilyName', sql2.varchar, 250, req.query.familyName)
                .execute('sp_registerUser', (err, result) => 
                {
                    console.log("Success"); 
                }).catch(function(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            })
         pool5.on('error', err => {
            console.log("Error");
         })
    } catch (err) {
    // ... error checks
        console.log("addRegistration: " + err)
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  It was my original code.

```
            .input('FBID', sql2.varchar, 250, req.query.id)
            .input('FBEmail', sql2.varchar, 250, req.query.email)
            .input('FBName', sql2.varchar, 250, req.query.memberName)
            .input('FamilyName', sql2.varchar, 250, req.query.familyName)
```

Needed to be changed to:

```
            .input('FBID', sql2.VarChar(250), req.query.id)
            .input('FBEmail', sql2.VarChar(250), req.query.email)
            .input('FBName', sql2.VarChar(250), req.query.memberName)
            .input('FamilyName', sql2.VarChar(250), req.query.familyName)
```

Ultimately I had the size as part of the value parameter.  It was all wrong.  Once I did it correctly, then the stored procedure executed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if this sounds glib, but I can’t see in your code where you have defined request - so my best answer would be that it is undefined as the error says...

Comment: Bravo mentioned the same thing.  That was a result of the cut and paste from another question.  I've taken that out (updated my question and errors).

Answer (score 0):

First create a connection  file for the sql server.

```
import mysql from 'mysql';
import config from 'config-yml';
import logger from '../logger';

/**
 * @description Creating pool to have simultanious connection to SQL.
 */
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: config.db.max_limit,
  host: config.db.host,
  user: config.db.user,
  port: config.db.port,
  password: config.db.password,
  database: config.db.name,
  debug: process.env.DB_DEBUG || false, // Set to true if you want to debug the database.
});

/**
 * @description Creates the database connection.
 */
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
  if (err) {
    if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
      logger.error('Database connection was closed.');
    }
    if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
      logger.error('Database has too many connections.');
    }
    if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
      logger.error('Database connection was refused.');
    }
  }
  if (connection) connection.release();
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Then create a export function  to execute the query code follows.

```
import pool from '../index';

const execQuery =  async (query, fn) => {
  pool.query(query, async (err, result, fields) => { // eslint-disable-line
    try {
      console.log(result[0][0]);
      fn(result[0][0]);
      return result;
    } catch (err) {
      return err;
    }
  });
};

export default execQuery;
```

After this write procedure in Workbench and call sql Procedure function

`call SO_CALLED_PROCEDURE(PASS_ARGUMENT)`;

it will work.